# Measure the peak stackpointer value and its PC location

Tags: gdb, stack, profiling, valgrind, benchmarking

For an analysis of different binaries, I need to measure the peak actual stack memory usage (not just the stack pages reserved, but the memory actually used). I was trying the following with gdb

```
watch $sp
commands
silent
if $sp < $spnow
  set $spnow=$sp
  set $pcnow=$pc
  print $spnow
  print $pcnow
  end
c
```

This appears to "work" when applied to `ls`, *except* even for a short-running program as `ls`, it doesn't actually appear to progress, but it's stuck in functions like "in strcoll_l () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6". Probably it just is too slow with this methodology.

I also looked into the valgrind `massif` tool. It can profile stack usage, but unfortunately can't seem to report in what part of the program the peak usage was encountered.

Comment: If `massif` is fast enough for you, you should consider patching it to capture a stack trace each time the maximum is exceeded. This being valgrind, the building blocks should all be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For an analysis of different binaries, I need to measure the peak actual stack memory usage

Your GDB approach

- works only for single-threaded programs
- is too slow to be practical (the `watch $sp` command forces GDB to single-step your program).

If you only care about stack usage at page granularity (and I think you should -- does it *really* matter whether the program used 1024 or 2000 bytes of stack?), then a much faster approach is to run the program in a loop, reducing its `ulimit -s` while the program successfully runs (you  could also binary search, e.g. start with default 8MB, then try 4, 2, 1, 512K, etc. until it fails, then increase stack limit to find the exact value).

For `/bin/ls`:

```
bash -c 'x=4096; while /bin/ls > /dev/null; do
         echo $x; x=$(($x/2)); ulimit -s $x || break; done'
4096
2048
1024
512
256
128
64
32
bash: line 1: 109951 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) /bin/ls > /dev/null
```

You can then find the `$PC` by looking at the `core` dump.

> I need the precise limits because I want to figure out what compiler optimizations cause what micro-changes to stack usages (even in the bytes range. along with .data and .text sizes).

I believe it's a fool's errand to attempt that.

In my experience, stack use is most affected by compiler inlining decisions. These in turn are most affected by precise compiler version and tuning, presence of runtime information (for profile-guided optimization), and precise source of the program being optimized.

A yes/no change to inlining decision can increase stack use by 100s of KBs in recursive programs, and minuscule changes to any of the above factors can change that decision.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I need the precise limits because I want to figure out what compiler optimizations cause what micro-changes to stack usages (even in the bytes range. along with .data and .text sizes). I wonder.. would it work to use `perf` and check for page-faults (or whatever event it is that triggers mapping of new stack memory), to be notified whenever the stack grows downwards a page? That should yield similar results

Comment: I agree with your edit. I wanted to measure the numbers only for a specific set of program (parts), to get some number to put into this table and argue later that it's not a really helpful number for the reasons you stated. But I think the effort doesn't really pay off so I will just drop my plans.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb The red zone on x86-64 will also throw your measurements off if you just record the value of the sp. Functions are allowed to use up to 128 bytes beyond the sp for local storage. So to be thorough, you'd need to look at machine code that accesses memory in that range, perhaps using a negative offset from rsp, perhaps using an offset from some other register.

Comment: @mark ah I see. So I guess I will fallback to discussing the effects qualitatively (what changes if we prevent inlining, constant propagation etc) rather than just measuring. I guess that will be more scientifically genuine. The actual thing I am trying to do is to investigate how this interoperates/compares with high level synthesis backend results where the effects are much more severe.